# Using PRAW to pull more than 1000 top entries

Tags: python, reddit, praw

How can I get [`praw`](https://praw.readthedocs.org/en/v2.1.21/) to download more than the 1000 of the top titles in a reddit sub? The following minimal working example stops at 1000:

```
import praw

subreddit_name  = "todayilearned"
user_agent = "TopHITS v0.1"
agent = praw.Reddit(user_agent=user_agent)
sub = agent.get_subreddit(subreddit_name)

submissions = sub.get_top_from_all(limit=None)
for result in submissions:
    print result
```

Comment: psaw might help https://github.com/dmarx/psaw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note the following paragraph from [the documentation of `praw`](https://praw.readthedocs.org/en/v2.1.21/pages/faq.html#non-obvious-behavior-and-other-need-to-know):

> We can at most get 1000 results from every listing, this is an
>   upstream limitation by reddit. There is nothing we can do to go past
>   this limit. But we may be able to get the results we want with the
>   search() method instead.

Comment: Great, that answers it. Do you know what _"we may be able to get the results we want"_ refers to?

Comment: @Hooked I don't know how they could overcome the 1000 results cap. Even by calling `search` method I do not get more than 1000 posts. Maybe you could get 1000 posts by date and then again start your search starting with the date of the 1000th result to get the next thousand and so on, but i have no idea how to achieve this with sorting by Top.